# Function notation [Beginners]

Tags: functions

I am given a question to "Show that $f(x) = f(-x)$ where $f(x) = x^2 - 2$. What type of function is it? "

I am not quite sure how to start this, my only problem with mathematics is **the wording of the questions**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So "show that" just means follow the example through to get the result:

$f(-x)=(-x)^2-2=x^2-2=f(x)$

Then it asks "what kind of function is this?" This is asking you what attribute the function has that makes it different from other functions.

This attribute is that $f(-x)=f(x)$, functions with this attribute are called "even".

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to show that $f(x) = f(-x)$. The first thing you should do is write up what they are.

$$ f(x) = x^2 - 2 $$

$$ f(-x) = (-x)^2 - 2 = x^2 - 2 $$

Now, what you should do next?

Comment: I'm not sure what you did, for the first part you just showed that f(x) = x^2 - 2 yes, but the second part you have 3 = signs? I don't know what to do from there

Comment: because $(-a)^2 = a^2 $ for any $a$

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a function has the property $f(x)=f(-x)$ , $f$ is called an $\textit{even}$ function.